# Training a variable-length document-level LSTM on variable-length sentence-level data using ngrams and majority voting

Tags: machine-learning, natural-language, lstm, ensemble-learning, sequential-analysis

Let's assume that I want to train a classification model for document-level input. The input is sequential (a sequence of tokens within a text). Documents may vary in length (*i.e.*, one or multiple sentences) but are typically 5 sentences long. Let's further assume that I am unable to collect 'real' data for my problem, but that I obtained a training data set that consists of independent, single sentences, that are representative of the type of sentences observed in the 'real' data for which the model is eventually trained. Unfortunately, the dataset seems to be slightly biased in terms of sequence lengths among classes (a typical model would 'cheat' by exploiting observed sentence length). How would I go about training and properly evaluating such model?

Based on the above I already made the following decisions:

- Inherent to the formulation of the problem, I can never evaluate the model on 'real world data', as simply I don't know how real world data looks like (more concretely: I don't know their length). Thus, I want to evaluate how well the model does with respect to different lengths of input, and, based on my knowledge of nature of the data, the expectation being that longer sequences perform better than shorter sequences.
- I will 'cut' the training set in slices of fixed length (*i.e.*, ngrams of tokens, *e.g.* slices of length 10, the length being a hyperparameter of the model) to avoid cheating (there is too less data to only include groups of sentences of a fixed size).
- The archictecture of the model will be a simple LSTM-like structure.

My idea is now to continue with making predictions based on *majority voting* (or a sum of softmaxes, or something of the like) on the independent predictions of multiple slices. For example, in one forward pass I would independently classify 5 slices of 10 tokens that have the same labels (randomly sampled) and let the final prediction be the majority value of those predictions. I have a couple of questions regarding such approach:

1. Should I make a loss term that is the sum of both all independent predictions of the individual samples (simple CrossEntropy per prediction) *and* a term for every of these predictions that quanitifies divergence from the majority vote (*e.g.* by KL divergence)? Would the latter not harm my model if the majority vote turns out to be wrong? Is there actually any benefit to incorporating these latter terms (is there any intuitive explanation for it making the model more 'consistent' in its predictions)?
2. Would it be wise to not set any fixed size of the group of samples that together form the majority vote? To just do an *What's in the batch*-approach? Say, if my batch size is 16, and there happen to be 3 samples of label 2 in the batch, I will perform the majority voting on 3 samples (for every occurring label in the batch, of course), and if there are 8, I perform on 8. Or should I pre-process my data in such a way that groups are always of a certain size, introducing another hyperparameter?
3. Would all of this be a good idea in the first place?

I am aware that there is some theory on 'ensemble learning' around, but I got the idea that these approaches are normally based on training multiple independent models (for example, multiple LSTMs), while here, I would like to train just *one*.

I am very eager for your answers and help!

*Edit:* Any literature complementing (or instead of) answers would of course also be appreciated! I am not only looking for the bare answers to this specific problem, but I am very interested into more theoretical explanations behind it as well.

*Edit 2*: The input sequences (for example, of length 10) are not necessarily unique to every label. It could be that identical sequences (correctly) appear in the dataset under multiple labels, but that their occurrence may be more typical for a certain label, or, that *in combination with other non-unique sequences* (other samples that contribute to the majority vote) it forms a clear hint towards a certain ensemble label. Then, every input sequence within the group poses a sort of 'evidence'. The more evidence (the larger the size of the group that forms a majority vote, or the larger the input document), the better predictions may be. This is the idea behind what I hope to achieve with the majority vote term in the loss.